# How to refer input id with a div id in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my div image:

[image]

I want to refer input id within gallery-1 dive. I tried this script:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        document.getElementById('#gallery-1','id_gallery_set-1-title').onchange = function() {
            var e = document.getElementById('#gallery-1','id_gallery_set-1-slug');
            if (!e._changed) { e.value = URLify(document.getElementById('#gallery-1','id_gallery_set-1-title').value, 50); }
            }  
       });
```

But it did not work. How do I refer input `id='id_gallery_set-1-title'` within `gallery-1` div?

Edit:

This code work for first formset:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        document.getElementById('id_gallery_set-0-title').onchange = function() {
            var e = document.getElementById('id_gallery_set-0-slug');
            if (!e._changed) { e.value = URLify(document.getElementById('id_gallery_set-0-title').value, 50); }
            }

       });
```

MY form html:

```
 <form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {{ formset.management_form }}
                        {% csrf_token %}

                        <legend>Event</legend>
                        <div class="event">
                        {{ form|crispy}}
                        </div>

                        <legend>
                            <div class="pull-right"><a href="#" class="btn btn-inverse add-photo"><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Add Photo</a></div>
                            Photo Gallery
                        </legend>
                        <div class="gallery form-inline">
                            {% for form in formset %}
                                {{ form|crispy }}
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                      <div class="form-actions">
                         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                       </div>
                     </form>
```

This is my full inspect of form:

[image]

```
<div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">

                    <form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input id="id_gallery_set-TOTAL_FORMS" name="gallery_set-TOTAL_FORMS" value="2" type="hidden"><input id="id_gallery_set-INITIAL_FORMS" name="gallery_set-INITIAL_FORMS" value="0" type="hidden"><input id="id_gallery_set-MIN_NUM_FORMS" name="gallery_set-MIN_NUM_FORMS" value="1" type="hidden"><input id="id_gallery_set-MAX_NUM_FORMS" name="gallery_set-MAX_NUM_FORMS" value="1000" type="hidden">
                        <input name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="QrSlXahV8qshQCefhNwcF1wrd4eWfDuX0UTslT3lYsyheDCdJ8GQrcBQ0IPrYqiK" type="hidden">

                        <legend>Event</legend>
                        <div class="event">


<div id="div_id_name" class="form-group"> <label for="id_name" class="control-label  requiredField">
                Name<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="controls "> <input class="textinput textInput form-control" id="id_name" maxlength="31" name="name" required="" type="text"> </div> </div> <div id="div_id_description" class="form-group"> <label for="id_description" class="control-label  requiredField">
                Description<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="controls "> <textarea class="textarea form-control" cols="40" id="id_description" name="description" rows="10" required=""></textarea> </div> </div> <div id="div_id_tags" class="form-group"> <label for="id_tags" class="control-label ">
                Tags
            </label> <div class="controls "> <select multiple="multiple" class="selectmultiple form-control" id="id_tags" name="tags">
</select> </div> </div>

                        </div>

                        <legend>
                            <div class="pull-right"><a href="#" class="btn btn-inverse add-photo"><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Add Photo</a></div>
                            Photo Gallery
                        </legend>
                        <div class="gallery form-inline">



<div id="div_id_gallery_set-0-title" class="form-group"> <label for="id_gallery_set-0-title" class="control-label  requiredField">
                Title<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="controls "> <input class="textinput textInput form-control" id="id_gallery_set-0-title" maxlength="35" name="gallery_set-0-title" type="text"> </div> </div> <div id="div_id_gallery_set-0-slug" class="form-group"> <label for="id_gallery_set-0-slug" class="control-label  requiredField">
                Slug<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="controls "> <input class="textinput textInput form-control" id="id_gallery_set-0-slug" maxlength="35" name="gallery_set-0-slug" readonly="readonly" type="text"> </div> </div> <div id="div_id_gallery_set-0-image" class="form-group"> <label for="id_gallery_set-0-image" class="control-label ">
                Image
            </label> <div class="controls "> <input class="clearablefileinput" id="id_gallery_set-0-image" name="gallery_set-0-image" type="file"> <p id="hint_id_gallery_set-0-image" class="help-block">Event Picture</p> </div> </div> <input id="id_gallery_set-0-id" name="gallery_set-0-id" type="hidden"> <div class="form-group"> <div id="div_id_gallery_set-0-DELETE" class="checkbox"> <label for="id_gallery_set-0-DELETE" class=""> <input class="checkboxinput" id="id_gallery_set-0-DELETE" name="gallery_set-0-DELETE" type="checkbox">
                    Delete












                </label> </div> </div> <input id="id_gallery_set-0-event" name="gallery_set-0-event" type="hidden">



            <div id="gallery-1">
                <label for="id_gallery_set-1-title">Title:</label><input id="id_gallery_set-1-title" maxlength="35" name="gallery_set-1-title" type="text">
<label for="id_gallery_set-1-slug">Slug:</label><input id="id_gallery_set-1-slug" maxlength="35" name="gallery_set-1-slug" readonly="readonly" type="text">
<label for="id_gallery_set-1-image">Image:</label><input id="id_gallery_set-1-image" name="gallery_set-1-image" type="file"><br><span class="helptext">Event Picture</span>
<label for="id_gallery_set-1-DELETE">Delete:</label><input id="id_gallery_set-1-DELETE" name="gallery_set-1-DELETE" type="checkbox"><input id="id_gallery_set-1-id" name="gallery_set-1-id" type="hidden"><input id="id_gallery_set-1-event" name="gallery_set-1-event" type="hidden">
            </div>
        </div>
                      <div class="form-actions">
                         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                       </div>
                     </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Console errors:

```
Unknown property ‘-moz-outline’.  Declaration dropped.create:1:4347
Unknown property ‘-moz-box-shadow’.  Declaration dropped.create:1:5300
Expected declaration but found ‘*’.  Skipped to next declaration.create:1:6215
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.create:1:9330

            <div id="gallery-1">
                <tr><th><label for="id_gallery_set-1-title">Title:</label></th><td><input id="id_gallery_set-1-title" maxlength="35" name="gallery_set-1-title" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_gallery_set-1-slug">Slug:</label></th><td><input id="id_gallery_set-1-slug" maxlength="35" name="gallery_set-1-slug" readonly="readonly" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_gallery_set-1-image">Image:</label></th><td><input id="id_gallery_set-1-image" name="gallery_set-1-image" type="file" /><br /><span class="helptext">Event Picture</span></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_gallery_set-1-DELETE">Delete:</label></th><td><input id="id_gallery_set-1-DELETE" name="gallery_set-1-DELETE" type="checkbox" /><input id="id_gallery_set-1-id" name="gallery_set-1-id" type="hidden" /><input id="id_gallery_set-1-event" name="gallery_set-1-event" type="hidden" /></td></tr>
            </div>
        photo.js:8:13
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented inste
```

[image]

Comment: You have a very odd mix of jQuery and vanilla JS going on there

Comment: `document.getElementById` only accepts one parameter. an `id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this clean syntax like:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('body').on('input','div[id^="gallery-"] input[id$="title"]',function() {
            el = $(this).parent().find('> input[id$="slug"]');
            el.val( URLify($(this).val(),50))
         });
  });
```

or change the ids to classes

note put this syntax in a  script tag at the bottom of the page

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('input','div[id^="gallery-"] input[id$="title"]',function() {
    el = $(this).parent().find('> input[id$="slug"]');
    el.val($(this).val() + 'xxxxxxxxxxxx');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>

<body>
  <div id="gallery-1">
    <input type="text" id="id_gallery_set-1-title">
    <input type="text" id="id_gallery-1-slug">

    <div id="gallery-2">
      <input type="text" id="id_gallery_set-2-title">
      <input type="text" id="id_gallery-2-slug">


    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="gallery-3">
    <input type="text" id="id_gallery_set-3-title">
    <input type="text" id="id_gallery-3-slug">


  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It didn't work. title and slug has more parameter. id_gallery_set-1-title

Comment: Your code work on the editor provided but in my case not work. I am using django formset. Working code for first formset I added to my question. But next formset not work. You can check my code.

Comment: Then could I post my model and formset

Comment: post all that you want

Comment: here is link of my model and form http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40583124/javascript-not-working-in-django-inline-formset-using-urlify-js

Comment: you need put this code at the bottom of your page not in the loop this code will execute for ALL your formsets

Comment: I past your code to the bottom of my base.html but still not working. The slug field should autopopulated when title field changed is my requirements.

Comment: can you paste the parsed code seems like you are inlining your gallery items

Comment: Same result, nothing change. Which code you want to see form html or view?

Comment: the parsed html

Comment: I added my form html to my question. You can check it.

Comment: I also added my form full inspect in my question. From that you can get idea.

Comment: damn man :( do you know what parsed html is ? why are you sending pictures is it so hard co click right on the dom element in the console and clic copy outerHtml?

Comment: from what i can see this should work if you put the code at the bottom of the page right before the body tag, any console errors?

Comment: I posted my parsed code. I didn't know it. Thanks for inform me. Bye today, Tomorrow will check it.

Comment: I pasted your code at the bottom of my form html. Still no luck. In the console I got two errors: ReferenceError: $ is not defined,
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null. In the same place my first formset work. If you closely look my parsed code you will see for first formset, div id="div_id_gallery_set-0-title" whereas in the second formset it is id="gallery-1".

Comment: you don't have the jquery library on your page man, no wander why it didn't work

Comment: I add <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> before script. Now Reference Error gone but slug not autopopulate.

Comment: what do you mean by autopopulate?

Comment: I mean when I type on child_name the slug field will automatically updated from the text of child_name in the form

Comment: All console errors are posted in my question. I also posted my inline formset  image, where you see first formset's slug was autopopulated from title but in second formset not.

Comment: Thanks man. It worked now. I accepted your answer. Could you tell me how to grab the inner id.

Comment: use attr('id');

Answer (score 0):

You could use `querySelector()` :

```
document.querySelector('#gallery-1 #id_gallery_set-1-title');
```

Not sure what you're trying to achieve but since you're using jQuery you could attach event like :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#gallery-1 #id_gallery_set-1-title').on('input', function(){
         //Get click element using '$(this)'

        if( CONDITION ){

        }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using javascript urlify.js. Does it work if I use querySelector()

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use parent selector #gallery-1 because you have id. Id must be unique for all DOM elements.
I don't know what is e._changed and what you want to do with this check, so I'm sure that if(!e._changed) will always returns true.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.querySelector('#id_gallery_set-1-title').addEventListener('change', function() {
        var e = document.querySelector('#id_gallery_set-1-slug');
        if (!e._changed) { 
          e.value = URLify(document.querySelector('#id_gallery_set-1-title').value, 50); }
        }  
   });
```

Comment: I tried using your code but not work. I want to slugify of title in form. But it stoped my form responding.

Comment: Please, describe what is your task in general.

Comment: In form I have more than two fields. one is title and other is slug. I want to slug field populated from title. When I typed title or change title field slug field automatically updated. It worked fine in normal form but in nested form it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

It should help you. whenever text change in textbox event occure in that text box refere by child of div with id **gallery-1**

```js
$("#gallery-1 > #id_gallery_set-1-title").on("input",function(){
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
  <body>
<div id="gallery-1">
  <input type="text" id="id_gallery_set-1-title">
  <input type="button" value="submit">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```